# How can I find my User ID (UID) from terminal?

Tags: command-line, user-management

The title says it all. What command I need to run from a terminal to find my user ID (UID)?

Comment: Use `echo $UID`?

Answer (score 471, accepted):

There are a couple of ways:

1. Using the [id](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/id/) command you can get the real and effective user and group IDs.

   ```
    id -u <username>
   ```

   If no username is supplied to `id`, it will default to the current user.
2. Using the shell variable. (It is not an environment variable, and thus is not available in `env`).

   ```
    echo $UID
   ```

Comment: How about GID ?

Comment: @kangear id -g <username>

Comment: It's worth noting that, due to the fact that the variables are resolved before being passed to a command, we have that `sudo echo ${UID}` prints out `1000` (or whatever your sudoer user's UID is), whereas `sudo id -u` prints out `0`.

Comment: The `username` is optional, defaulting to yourself.  Maybe square brackets would be better for indicating this, instead of angle brackets.

Comment: The second part of this answer is **wrong**. The variable in question is explicitly _not_ an environment variable. It's a shell variable. Big difference. You can see this with `echo $UID` versus `env|grep ^UID` in Bash, for example. This means in particular that the first method is more robust and the second will only work in shell scripts, not - say - in something like Python (`python -c 'import os; print(os.environ)'` to see the *environment*).

Comment: @0xC0000022L That seems to be the case indeed. I get 1000 from `echo $UID` and an empty line from `$ printenv UID`.

Answer (score 112):

Simply try

```
id
```

This will return your user ID, group ID, and all your groups.

Comment: or `id -u` to see just the UID

Comment: Yepp. Prefer Jobin's answer, if you need to avoid parsing the output.

Comment: so much easier with `id -u` and `id -g`. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 19):

Try also :

```
getent passwd username
```

This will display user id , group id and home directory .

Or:

```
grep username /etc/passwd
```

Comment: why to try long or alternative command while `echo $UID` and `id -u` is simple and exact **according to question**?

Comment: thats right , but its good to know all options

Answer (score 10):

You can use `id` command.

[Manpage](https://www.ma.utexas.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?id)

Answer (score 5):

##### Get the User ID (UID) and Group ID (GID) for the running user

```bash
id -u  # user ID (UID)
id -g  # group ID (GID)
```

Example run and output for the active user (myself):

```bash
$ id -u
1000
$ id -g
1000
```

and for the root user (via `sudo`):

```bash
$ sudo id -u
[sudo] password for gabriel: 
0
$ sudo id -g
0
```

Note that the first user is generally `1000` for both the UID and GID, and the root user is generally `0` for both the UID and GID.