# Local network share password is not accepted

Tags: networking, password

I have the same issue as, "ubuntu 18.04 local network share password".
I have Ubuntu 18.04 on two machines, with the same usernames and passwords, connected with a cross-over Ethernet cable.
I can see the shares on the other machine, both-ways. I can access the shares if I set them up for Anonymous access, but I can't access the shares with the password required setting. The password (same on both machines) is not accepted.

Comment: Are the UIDs the same too? Are you singing Samba?  Are the config files identical?  Please [edit] your question to give us a bit more tangible information...

Comment: I should close this question. I don't know how to answer the questions about UIDs and config files.

Comment: Ubuntu works differently from Windows: on top of Uiser names and passwords, the UIDs must be identical.  [Go here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/468236/how-can-i-find-my-user-id-uid-from-terminal) to find out...  **0:-)**